# Value of type 'Type' has no subscripts Error Swift

Tags: json, swift, sorting

Trying to sort the array of JSON objects in the array by "name" alphabetically. Gives error of "Value of type 'IndividualContact' has no subscripts" Not sure what that means. Any help is appreciated.

```
class Contacts{
    var contact = [IndividualContact]()

    init?(data2: Data) {
        do {
            if let json2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data2) as? [String: Any], let body = json2["data2"] as? [String: Any] {

                if let contacts = body["contacts"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                    self.contact = ( contacts.map { IndividualContact(json2: $0) } )
                }

            }

           contact.sorted(by: { ($0["name"] as! String) < ($1["name"] as! String) })
        } catch {
            print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
            return nil
        }

    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of Code]

Comment: It means what it says. Hint: You are dealing with a struct or class, not with a dictionary. And don't post images, post text.

Comment: Maybe using `Codable` would simplify things and also not to decode json in `init`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that your object (`IndividualContact`) doesn't provide an implementation for the subscript token, i.e. `[...]`. While you *could* provide that implementation in your struct/class, doing so might be overkill in this situation. You probably just want to call `$0.name` in your `sorted(by:)` closure:

`contact.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })`

If you really do want to use the `$0["name"]` syntax, then you can provide such an implementation. It might look something like this:

```
subscript(key: String) -> String {
    get {
        switch key {
        case "name":
            return self.name
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
    set {
        ...
    }
}
```

More info on subscripts can be found here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html

Comment: It should be mentioned that implementing subscription in a class to access properties is fiddle-faddle.

Comment: Very true. In some very specific cases you might be able to use dynamic member lookup to do something fancy, but generally speaking it's not very "Swift-y".

Comment: If you chose unwisely to implement `subscript`, you should at least make it return an optional so you can return `nil` for unknown keys.