# Trying to make the search bar functionality filter the names of the contacts which are coming from a json object into an array of strings

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchbar

Want to convert my json object into an array of just names so I can use the search bar to search for different names and filter it.

```
    "data2": {
    "id": 1,
    "contacts": [
        {
            "name": "Molly",
            "pictureUrl": "molly"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cathy",
            "pictureUrl": "molly"
        },

        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "pictureUrl": "bob"
        },
        {
            "name": "Nick",
            "pictureUrl": "clothes"
        }
    ],



},
"error": 0,
"message": "Success"
```

This is the json file with the object:

```
var contact = [IndividualContact]()

init?(data2: Data) {
    do {
        if let json2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data2) as? [String: Any], let body = json2["data2"] as? [String: Any] {

            if let contacts = body["contacts"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                self.contact = ( contacts.map { IndividualContact(json2: $0) } )

                //Expected: ["Molly", "Bob", "Cathy"]

            }


 }
```

Comment: `let filterArray = contacts.compactMap{$0["name"] as? String }`

Comment: How many accounts do you have? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467508/value-of-type-type-has-no-subscripts-error-swift